# IComparable<string> implementation - cannot access Length of string

Tags: c#, collections

```
    class MyComparer : IComparable<string>
    {


        public int CompareTo(string second)
        {
            int diff = this.Length - second.Length;
            return ...
        }

    }
```

That code doesn't work because "MyComparer" does not contain a definiton for "Length", so how to access Length?

Comment: why do you expect that your `MyComparer` should have a property `Length` ? are you trying to compare 2 strings? it is not clear yet

Comment: What is the exact purpose of this? `String` already implements `IComparable<String>`.

Comment: Theoretically, `MyComparer` would contain a string property that you'd use for comparison.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare two strings with IComparable.

Comment: VisualStudio marks is as an error:

" "MyComparer" does not contain a definiton for "Length" "

Comment: Well you can't. So do what @PatrickHofman says, and use `IComparer<T>`.

Comment: @Yas: string is already capable of comparing itself with another string

Comment: I'm obligated to use IComparable. It's an exercise.

Comment: I'm want to sort it different way than default..

Comment: @Yas: Maybe your class has a property `Name`. Then it could  make sense to implement `IComparable<string>` and then return `this.Name.Length - second.Length;`

Comment: I'm using IComparable for SortedDictionary <string, long> and I have to sort by Key Length (I'm obligated to use IComparable).

Answer (score 2):

You are implementing the wrong interface. You need [`IComparer<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int diff = x.Length - y.Length;

    }
}
```